# Global Map Mutations

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use have to drop the following code in every single component in my SPA.

```
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
```

Is there a way to make this import "Global"? Even putting in in my main app.js does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe global mixins solve this problem.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin

Comment: Yes, it was the only solution I found that looks ok. I thought I was maybe missing something from Vue framework itself.